# Higher sample moments of the $n$-consecutive sum of $N$ random variables ($N>n$)

Tags: statistics, random-variables, expectation, variance

Let $\mathbf{X}$ be an $N$-vector of independent random variables drawn from some distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$:
$$
\mathrm{E}\left[x_1\right]=\cdots=\mathrm{E}\left[x_N\right]=\mu, \mathrm{Var}\left[x_1\right]=\cdots\mathrm{Var}\left[x_N\right]=\sigma^2
$$
Let $\mathbf{Y}$ be the vectors of $n$-consecutive sums of $\mathbf{X}$:
$$y_i=\sum_{j=i}^{i+n-1}x_j,i=1,\cdots,N-n+1\tag{1}\label{1}$$
or
$$\mathbf{Y}=\mathbf{X}\mathbf{M}\tag{2}\label{2}$$
where
$$\mathbf{M}=\begin{bmatrix}
\left.\begin{matrix}
 1& 0&\cdots&0\\ 
 1& 1&\cdots&0\\ 
 \vdots & \vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\ 
\end{matrix}\right\}&N-n\\
\left.\begin{matrix}
1& 1 &\cdots&1\\
0&1&\cdots&1\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
0&0&\cdots&1\end{matrix}\right\}&n
\end{bmatrix}$$
I have worked out the results of $\mathrm{E}\left[\overline{y_i^r}\right]$, $\mathrm{Var}\left[\overline{y_i^r}\right]$, $\mathrm{E}\left[\overline{\left(y_i-\overline{y_i}\right)^r}\right]$ and $\mathrm{Var}\left[\overline{\left(y_i-\overline{y_i}\right)^r}\right]$ for $r=1,2$, and also $\mathrm{E}\left[\overline
{y_i}^2\right]$ and $\mathrm{Var}\left[\overline
{y_i}^2\right]$, if useful. I am hindered by the cases of $r=3,4$.  Can they be expressed by the known results above?

For example, I see no hope in expanding $\overline{y_i^4}$ by eq. \eqref{1}, neither can I express $\overline{y_i^4}$ into some quadratic forms by eq. \eqref{2}. I found on the Internet some discussions about the maximum of partial sum of random variables (for example, http://msp.org/pjm/1974/52-2/pjm-v52-n2-p27-p.pdf), but no discussions of the sample moments of it. One special characteristic of the current problems is $y_i$ and $y_{i+1}$ are highly overlapped and hence not independent. I know limited mathematical tools but are willing to learn.